# Firebase ApiFuture to CompletableFuture in a reactive stack

Tags: firebase, spring-webflux

I am using the Firebase Admin Java SDK in a server side Spring WebFlux environment. The Firebase SDK provides two methods for each operation. A synchronous ".doOperation()" method which returns a result and a ".doOperationAsync()" method which returns an instance of ApiFuture.

[The Javadoc for ApiFuture can be found here.](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.1.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html)

ApiFuture extends from java.util.concurrent.Future, which is no longer supported by Mono.fromFuture().

Is there a way to convert Googles ApiFuture into a Mono?

Comment: As I see ApiFuture doesn't have any callback method which would expose the result type. So the only option to get the result is calling get on the Future and wrap it with Mono.fromCallable and delegating to a thread pool.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Thanks for the comment. That is exactly what I ended up doing. It seems to work well, but isn't ideal. I hoped I was missing some key part of this issue but it doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 1):

Some utility methods for you

```java
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> toCompletableFuture(ApiFuture<T> apiFuture) {
        final CompletableFuture<T> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ApiFutures.addCallback(apiFuture,
                new ApiFutureCallback<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        cf.completeExceptionally(t);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(T result) {
                        cf.complete(result);
                    }
                },
                MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
        return cf;
    }

    public static <T> Mono<T> toMono(ApiFuture<T> apiFuture) {
        return Mono.create(sink -> ApiFutures.addCallback(apiFuture,
                new ApiFutureCallback<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        sink.error(t);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(T result) {
                        sink.success(result);
                    }
                },
                MoreExecutors.directExecutor()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to convert [ApiFuture](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.1.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html) to [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), which can be used with [Mono.fromFuture](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromFuture-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture-):

```
internal class ApiCompletableFuture<V>(
    private val future: ApiFuture<V>,
    executor: Executor = directExecutor(),
) : CompletableFuture<V>(), ApiFutureCallback<V> {
    init {
        ApiFutures.addCallback(future, this, executor)
    }

    override fun cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean {
        future.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
        return super.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
    }

    override fun onSuccess(result: V) {
        complete(result)
    }

    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
        completeExceptionally(t)
    }
}
```